# select first index in collection where like

Tags: java

I feel sometimes that I'm reinventing the wheel.

I'm wondering if there are any utility methods in java/jakarta commons/guava/?, that will go deeper in the collection and do something (test, modify, remove) with the elements.

I wrote this method and now I feel that there is some one-liner that can do it.

```
/**
 * Find index of first line that contains search string.
 */
public static int findIdx(List<String> list, String search) {
  for (int i = 0, n = list.size(); i < n; i++)
    if (list.get(i).contains(search))
      return i;
  return -1;
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing `for (int i = 0, n = list.size(); i < n; i++)` instead of `for (int i = 0, i < list.size(); i++)`?

Comment: @Bhesh It looks like like an optimization in case the size() operation is expensive.  But it also assumes the list size remains fixed while looping, which seems dangerous to me.

Comment: This is my style. I didn't checked how expensive the call to size() method is.

Answer (score 5):

Guava has `Iterables.indexOf` with a predicate:

```
int index = Iterables.indexOf(list, new Predicate<String> {
        @Override public boolean apply(String input) {
            return input.contains(search);
        }
    });
```

Not much better, admittedly - and you need to make `search` final. But at least with Java 8 you'll be able to write something like:

```
int index = Iterables.indexOf(list, input => input.contains(search));
```

(Or at least something *like* that. And possibly in an extension method syntax...)

Comment: Very elegant, not a one-line but beautifull. I was actually playing with commons CollectionUtils.find, but that method doesn't give an index...

Answer (score 2):

Guava has what you want in [`Iterables.indexOf()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html), although I wouldn't exactly argue that it'll make your code more readable:

```
public static int findIdx(List<String> list, final String search) {
  return Iterables.<String> indexOf(list, new Predicate<String>() {
    public boolean apply(String s) {
      return s.contains(search);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: TNX for your ready to use function. Guava is very powerfull but it's still a lot of typing.

Comment: Yeah...  Java and functional programming don't play nicely.  So much boilerplate instantiating anonymous `Function` / `Predicate` classes :(